# target first-child css styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I am using styled-components and want to target the first child of `Text`, but am unable to do so.

```
const Text = styled.p`
    font-size: 12px;
    &:first-child {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
`;

... component

return(
   <div>
      <p>I am just regular text</p>
      <p>Me too</p>
      <Text>Hello Joe</Text> // this should have the margin bottom
      <Text>Goodbye</Text >
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Finally, I got your issue. The styled component confuses with the first two native `p` tag (from my perspective) and that's the reason why the CSS is not applied.

I will use a workaround like this:

```js
const Text = styled.p`
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;
    &:nth-child(3) {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        color: red !important;
    }
`;
```

By doing this, you are selecting the third child (which include the first two `p` tag) for the CSS

OR, you can do something like this: Adding a class name for the tag and giving CSS for that class.

```js
const Text = styled.p`
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  &.colors {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: red !important;
  }
`;

 <div>
    <p>I am just regular text</p>
    <p>Me too</p>
    <Text className="colors">Hello Joe</Text>
    <Text>Goodbye</Text>
</div>
```

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZooJw?editors=0010)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I updated my question slightly, there is a `span` within the `p` tag, would that have something to do with it not working? Sorry for not including earlier. Also, when I use your code it is all in blue, so for some reason first-child not working

Comment: so strange, still not working for me here. Will give ye both upvotes anyway

Comment: @Thinker lol I've written almost the exact same words and also provided a demo using two different colors. I think we might be css-soulmates,.. just kidding.. :D

Comment: can you check the updated question - this is why it is off

Comment: @peterflanagan you are correct. Now I am getting the issue. It's becz of the first two `p` tag. I have updated my solutions. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 22):

Use like this

```
const Text = styled.p`
   font-size: 12px;
    > * {
      &:first-child {
         margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
`;
```

Comment: This works well, however updating the answer to include why it works would be extra useful.

Comment: Is this a "because React" thing or is it a "because CSS" thing?

Answer (score 10):

There shouldn't be a space between the `&` and the `:first-child`

```
&:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: that is what I thought too, and had tried this also, but it doesn't work

Comment: Odd. Is the font-size property is applying fine?

Comment: I updated my question slightly, there is a `span` within the `p` tag, would that have something to do with it not working? Sorry for not including earlier.

Comment: @dan is right, it was the empty space. Check this demo: Everything is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/8882z34y19

Comment: can you check the updated question - this is why it is off

Answer (score 4):

it's better to use :last-of-type on certain styled component instead of using :nth-child and it works perfectly

```
export default styled.div`
    :last-of-type {
        background: red;
    }`
```

```js
const Text = styled.p`
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;
    &:nth-child(3) {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        color: red !important;
    }
`;
```

Comment: I like the `last-of-type` approach. A little more modular (e.g. component styling is kept specific to the element itself, rather than interfering with a child).

Answer (score 0):

### This is possible, but probably not correct

This totally is possible, as we see with the other answers. The issue is that with first-child or nth-child solutions you tend to end up reaching down the DOM hierarchy, creating all sorts of specificity issues that can be difficult to untangle later.

The beauty of Styled Components is you typically apply styles to the element itself, meaning your styles stay tightly coupled to your components. Components become portable, and it's easy to find the line of CSS that might be causing an issue in a complex app.

for example, if I were to style the first `<a>` in a list item in a ul differently, I'd need to put `:first-child` further up the hierarchy, breaking encapsulation.

### Treat your styles as a function

The simple solution to this is to recognise that the styled component is a function that can receive parameters:

```
<StyledListItem index={index} />
```

Then receive that parameter in the component:

```
export const StyledListItem = styled.li<{index?: number}>`
  ${
    ({index}) => {
      if (index === 3) return `
        color: red;
        border: 2px dotted pink;
      `
      if (index === 0) return `
        border-left: none
      `
    }
  }
`
```

CSS in JS facilitates these kinds of programmatic solutions, and your life will be easier if you leverage them.

Answer (score 0):

try using the style with the HTML tag you want to style,
In your case, it would be:

```css
p:first-child {
// your style here
}
```